# Wireless not showing (wifi adapter not found) at all on Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell Precision 5510

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, 19.10, iwlwifi

My Kernel version is `5.3.0-26-generic`

output of `rfkill list all`

```
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

5: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:132 memory:ddb00000-ddb01fff
*-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:a6:94:b2:78
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 
 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:1
   logical name: enp0s20f0u1
   serial: ee:f5:b6:ae:05:81
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug- 
   2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.254 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Output of `dmesg | grep wifi`

```
[    2.838370] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.885952] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.885954] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.886505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.985347] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    2.992104] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.992490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.059470] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: e4:a4:71:03:41:b1
[    3.060066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[    3.060194] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.060196] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 6
[    3.060197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.77d01142.0
[    3.060198] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00001392 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    3.060199] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002F1 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.060200] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    3.060201] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00012536 | branchlink2
[    3.060202] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0001C2FE | interruptlink1
[    3.060203] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[    3.060203] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000010D | data1
[    3.060204] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[    3.060205] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | data3
[    3.060206] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    3.060207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00001819 | tsf low
[    3.060208] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    3.060209] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    3.060210] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000181A | time gp2
[    3.060210] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000009 | uCode revision type
[    3.060211] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000024 | uCode version major
[    3.060212] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x77D01142 | uCode version minor
[    3.060213] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000201 | hw version
[    3.060214] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x18489008 | board version
[    3.060215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0010016A | hcmd
[    3.060216] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00122080 | isr0
[    3.060216] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    3.060217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x28201802 | isr2
[    3.060218] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x004000C0 | isr3
[    3.060219] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | isr4
[    3.060220] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0010016A | last cmd Id
[    3.060221] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[    3.060221] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00004FD6 | l2p_control
[    3.060222] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000820 | l2p_duration
[    3.060223] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.060224] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.060225] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.060226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x08081421 | timestamp
[    3.060227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000818 | flow_handler
[    3.060287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.060287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 7
[    3.060288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[    3.060289] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.060292] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0086B38 | umac branchlink2
[    3.060293] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC008D6CA | umac interruptlink1
[    3.060294] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC008D678 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.060294] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000800 | umac data1
[    3.060295] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC008D678 | umac data2
[    3.060296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    3.060297] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000024 | umac major
[    3.060298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x77D01142 | umac minor
[    3.060299] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0886DEC | frame pointer
[    3.060299] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0886DEC | stack pointer
[    3.060300] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0010016A | last host cmd
[    3.060301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.060318] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    3.060323] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF9C99D80 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.060327] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC465164C | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.060332] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0F490C92 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.060336] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000A056 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.060341] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xE3725170 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.060345] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x90B22E2C | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.060350] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5419E086 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.060354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF6BD255C | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.060359] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x03000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.060366] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.060374] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.060381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0BADCAFE | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.060388] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT calibrations: -5
[    3.060390] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    3.307895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.320476] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Comment: Alll output looks perfectly well. Please add output if `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have added the output of `dmesg | grep wifi`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that seems to be fixed already. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1808389

Connect to the internet by other means: wire or phone tethering and update your system by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot and check Wi-Fi.

Comment: I tried this and still could not see any wifi (still says No adapter found for wifi), Please help

Comment: i noticed that phy0 wireless lan is missing from `rfkill list`

Comment: It is missing because firmware load crashed.

Comment: Please how can I solve this, since I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar problem. 
Try this:

1. disable Secure Boot in UEFI (BIOS) settings
2. reinstall linux firmware `sudo apt install linux-firmware`
3. add in grub the parameter pcie_aspm=off :

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

   Add `pcie_aspm=off` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
4. reboot

It worked for me, 
Good luck!